# How to use #[deprecated] for renaming public struct in backwards compatible way?

Tags: rust, semantic-versioning

I see that I can use the #[deprecated] marker, but somehow it is not working in the following workflow:

1. I renamed all my `MyOldStruct` to `MyNewStruct` in my library.
2. Added a #deprecated note to `pub use MyNewStruct as MyOldStruct`.

```
pub struct MyNewStruct{};

#[deprecated]
pub use MyOldStruct as MyNewStruct;
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong here? I am viewing if it shows as deprecated in cargo docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a type alias:

```
#[deprecated]
pub type MyOldStruct = MyNewStruct;
```

See it emit a warning on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c082600588947cd1875523cfdf53938).

---

I will note that using a type alias for renaming and deprecating things doesn't work for everything: an aliased tuple struct can't use the new name construct a value as shown in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html), and this method obviously  doesn't work for traits since they aren't types and we don't have [trait aliases](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1733-trait-alias.html) yet.